# Javascript Submit form with custom button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mootools

Imagine an HTML form with multiple submit buttons,
Im trying to write javascript function to submit this form with one specific button,
usually we use:

```
form.submit();
```

but it doesnt specify which button is pressed,

any Ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? why not submit with the submit button? why do you need JavaScript\Jquery for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fire it directly?

```
document.querySelector("#someButton").onclick();
```

Or if you're wanting to fire the submit button directly of a form, why not

```
document.querySelector("#someForm input[type='submit']").onclick();
```

Comment: thnx
I figured it out with some tweaks for mootools cuz I prefer it :D

Comment: the second example wont work in this particular situation, cuz we have more than one input button with type submit!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you'd submit the form in an event handler that is bound to the click event on the desired button:

```
$('.trueSubmitFormButton').click(function(){
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: this is not what I meant, your code adds the ability of sending the form to the element, but I want a Function to send the form like one specific submit button is pressed.

Comment: the form has multiple submit buttons, and pressing each button would cause different things to happen (its done through server side scripting which is no problem) I want to press an specific button from a js function